# Having trouble understanding the use of symbols in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble understanding the use of symbol in rails. I understand that in most cases, symbol is just name of something(or string). For example `:name => "John Doe", :email => "johndoe@gmail.com"` . However, in the following example, the symbol `:post` is not defined anywhere in the program, but still being used. `<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>` What does this `:post` symbol associated with? and how do i look at symbols when working in rails?

Comment: `:post` is not associated with anything. It's just a [literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html), like `123`. (This is a Ruby question that is not specific to Rails, so you should remove the Rails tag. )

Comment: See also [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Symbol.html).

Comment: I think a combination of CarySwoveland's comment, and meagar's and tadman's answers would be a complete, acceptable answer to this question.

Comment: Simply put symbols are immutable strings. Here's a really great explanation: http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings

Answer (score 4):

Symbols are not "names of things", and they are not associated with anything except themselves. A symbol is just that: A symbol. It's associated *internally* with a unique identifier, but this is an implementation detail.

In this case the symbol `:post` has no role except to communicate to the `form_for` function that it should look for a variable called `post` in the calling scope and use it to populate the form's fields. The symbolic representation of the symbol is used to help the method locate its variable and name its fields, but the symbol `:post` isn't associated with anything defined elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i guess im confused about how does a particular symbol "know" where to locate it's variable? does it have to do with the name of the symbol itself? say :post means look for the local variable called "post" ?

Comment: No. Symbols have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with variables. A Symbol is a Symbol. It may be *used* to denote a variable, but it may just as well be used to denote an enumerated value, or a US Interstate Highway. There is *no* relationship at all between a Symbol `:post` and a variable `post`. None.

Answer (score 2):

By using `:post` in your code you've defined the `:post` symbol, these are created automatically any time a new name is encountered or a string is converted to a symbol manually via `to_sym`.

In general terms symbols are more efficient when they're used frequently and repeatedly when compared to their string counterparts. They're "internalized strings", or "interns" in some descriptions, effectively added to a dictionary internally.

`"post"` is a string that might exist in many, many places within your code, each one of those could be an independent string with memory allocated to it. Comparing one of them to another requires doing a string comparison.

On the other hand `:post` always refers to the same object. This makes comparisons significantly easier, plus the memory is allocated once and once only.

Comment: IMHO, the 'efficiency' aspect of Symbols is just additional confusion for a new Rubyist (nubyist?). It's good information on "why symbols vs strings", but not, in my opinion, a good answer to "what are symbols".

Comment: Their entire purpose relates to efficiency, so it's hard to side-step that issue.